# How to disable Stripe button

Tags: html, stripe-payments

The Stripe button is shown using the below code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['publishable_key']?>"
            data-currency="GBP"
            data-amount=<?php echo $planDetails->amount?>
            data-description="<?php echo $PackageDetails->pkg_description; ?>"
            data-label="Update Payments">
            </script>
    </form>
```

Its working fine now but I want to disable the button for trial users. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are looking for a plain js solution.
You can easily do that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].disabled=true;
```

(This piece of code obviously assume you have only a single button with this class name)

http://jsfiddle.net/xfxn8bvx/
(notice that the script is running after DOM was loaded).

Comment: Thanq Morkadosh,Working Fine.

Comment: @GeethikaSJ Please mark answer as correct and vote up :)

Comment: Sure,I Have Some clarification about stripe, once user subscription per month it will automatically done in stripe Account? For example,once user pay $4 june month mean it will automatically debit the particular user acccount July month,I am right?

Comment: Actually I am not very familiar with stripe, so I can't really answer your question. Your question was a general JS question regardless of stripe, so I was able to answer it without knowing this service.

Comment: Does this create race conditions? What if your script finishes before the stripe script finishes?